# Change 'Optional' Label In Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: woocommerce

I want to change 'Optional' label in Woocommerce Checkout. My site is in another language, however for some reason Woocommerce shows this word in English. I want to change it to 'Neprivaloma'

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: @JustinR. This link is #1 in Google for 'woocommerce change (optional) label' request. Instead of playing 'smart' you could just answer the question

Comment: @Paradoxetion If it's the #1 result in a google search then it shows that OP did not make an attempt to research and answer their own question.  OP's question additionally does not meet SO community standards as it lacks a complete, minimal, and verifiable example.  As such, we can only guess what OP is really trying to achieve.  Maybe you can find something better to do with your time than chide people who are trying to help others understand the easiest and best way to get a quality answer from the community.

Comment: @JustinR. - easiest way is to answer. #1 in Google means that not a lot of people tried to solve it before. 'Google it' is not a good way to spend time - better ignore or downvote or flag if worry so much about community

Comment: Something ranking well in Google does not mean that a lot of people tried to solve the same issue.  Google SERP rankings are based on a huge number of factors.  It's also just your opinion that Googling answers is a waste of time. 
 Many of us find it extremely useful living in the age of information.  Regardless, I'm not going to spend my time arguing with you in the comments.  I stand by my comments which you personally can agree with or not.

Comment: It means that when others will try to fix it they'll see this question with your 'Oh, plebs, just learn to google'. Just saying but you already posted way more lines of text than me and way less code =)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find 'code way' of doing this, but possible to do with CSS hack:

```
span.optional {
    font-size: 0 !important;
}

span.optional:after {
    content: 'YOUR TEXT';
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

With that we hide default label by setting its font-size to 0 and show our own by giving it font-size back.

Comment: Why would you hide a label when you can change the content of it?  Woocommerce has hooks and filters.  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: @JustinR. And again I don't see a single line of code from you. I bet all people saw this manual. There is nothing about '(optional)' part in it. What's next. You would recommend me this link - https://codex.wordpress.org/ or this - http://php.net/docs.php. I've made the best answer I could. Propose better one

Comment: @JustinR. 
      $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 1;
      $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'Phone';
      $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = 'Phone Number';
      $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['required'] = false;

This code still gives Phone (optional). Review links you provide, oke?